# How can I fix the Android app crash after clicking the 'Next' button on my app's register screen?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm working on android app that have two types of user, in the register screen after clicking the next button the user is saved to the database but the app crash before starting the next activity

Here is my register screen code

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        mAuth =FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mEmail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.regemail);
        mPassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mconpassword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.conpassword);
        mbregister=(Button) findViewById(R.id.regbtn);
        mlogrdrct=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.logredrc);
        FirebaseAuthListener=new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
        mbregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String email= mEmail.getText().toString();
                final String password= mPassword.getText().toString();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
                    mEmail.setError("Enter email");
                }else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                    mPassword.setError("Enter Password");
                }else if        (!TextUtils.equals(mPassword.getText().toString(),mconpassword.getText().toString())) {

                    mconpassword.setError("Passwords are not matching");
                }
                else {

                        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "register failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }else {
                                String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                DatabaseReference curr_user_db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("individuals").child(uid);
                                curr_user_db.setValue(true);
                                Intent intent=new Intent(register.this, registerSTEP2.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
        }});
```

and in the firebase authentecation the used detail are stored but the app crash before starting the new activity, but in the realtime database in the user node no password or email is stored

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You have to add the crash logs here, although I suspect it has something to do with registering the onClickListener in the AuthStateListener itself. Don't do that kind of implementation.